# Can't bring cassandra and celery together

Tags: python, cassandra, celery, python-3.5

I'm trying the the example to use celery and cassandra together:
http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/cqlengine/third_party.html
But without luck.

I get this exception the I'm starting the worker with:
$ celery -A tasks worker -l INFO

```
[2016-06-12 14:11:53,609: ERROR/Worker-1] Process Worker-1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/lutz/work/truncated/truncated-worker/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/billiard/process.py",  line 292, in _bootstrap
self.run()
File "/Users/lutz/work/truncated/truncated-worker/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 292, in run
self.after_fork()
File "/Users/lutz/work/truncated/truncated-worker/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 395, in after_fork
self.initializer(*self.initargs)
File "/Users/lutz/work/truncated/truncated-worker/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/concurrency/prefork.py", line 84, in process_initializer
signals.worker_process_init.send(sender=None)
File "/Users/lutz/work/truncated/truncated-worker/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/utils/dispatch/signal.py", line 166, in send
response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
TypeError: cassandra_init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sender'
```

I'm Using osx el Capitan, python 3.5.1, Celery 3.1.23 and cassandra 3.5.

So any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Your `cassandra_init` signal handler function needs to accept arbitrary keyword arguments.

Simply change the line:

```
def cassandra_init():
```

into:

```
def cassandra_init(**kwargs):
```

For more information about Celery signals, see the user guide at:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#basics

Note: It would be helpful if you also submitted some kind of report to the author of that tutorial.  Celery signal handlers have always required the keyword arguments, so it's sad to have non-working examples out there.